drizzle orm useLiveQuery doesn't detect parameters change
I am using drizzle orm for sqlite with useLiveQuery.
Habits are returned and then based on habits ids I want to fetch tasks.
But I always get 0 results.
If I pass directly [1,2] I get result.
It looks like that useLiveQuery doesn't detect changes and doesn't react to habits ids.
const { data: habits } = useLiveQuery(
    db.query.habits.findMany({
      where: eq(schema.habits.userId, parseInt(userId as string)),
    })
  );
  
  const ids = habits ? habits.map((h) => h.habitId) : [];
  
  const { data: tasks } = useLiveQuery(
    db.query.tasks.findMany({
      where: inArray(schema.tasks.habitId, ids),
    })
  );


What kind of version do you use for drizzle-orm ?

"drizzle-orm": "^0.37.0", this is in react native

if you check the doc. You'll find that the useLiveQuery hook can get two args the first one is the query and the 2nd is list of dependencies.
So in your case i guess you just need the list of dependencies ([ids])
 const { data: tasks } = useLiveQuery(
    db.query.tasks.findMany({
      where: inArray(schema.tasks.habitId, ids)
    }),
    [ids]
  )

